# Importing from views directory

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my project I have an app called `api` where I keep my viewsets in a directory called `views`. I keep getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api.views.book'; 'api.views' is not a package` where I import in my `api/urls.py`

**api/urls.py**

```
from rest_framework import routers
from api.views.book import BookViewset

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'books', BookViewset, 'books')

api_urls = router.urls
```

In my main urls.py I'm doing this:

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
from api.urls import api_urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('api', include(api_urls)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I didn't get an error until I imported `api_urls`

I should mention that `api` is included in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file in the api/views directory?

Comment: @IainShelvington Please make this an answer, this was my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a file named `__init__.py` in a directory to make it a package, then you can import from it

In your case you need a file `api/views/__init__.py`